# yql?q= use "store://store-id" as OpenDataTable doesn't work anymore

Tags: yql

I've created an account Yahoo for a few years.
I created some **OpenDataTables** through the old yql console, containing javascript to extract html code from some web pages.

Data extraction is done as follows:

https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=use"store://my-store-token" as OpenTable; select * from OpenTable where url="http://myUrl" and xpath='// myXpath' and wparams="myParams"&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=

Data extraction has always been successful until yesterday.

Tonight, suddenly all scheduled calls have started producing the following error:

```
{"error": {"lang": "en-US", "description": "**Table not accessible**"}}
```

what is going on.
It is **extremely important** for me to restore the correct functioning of the extractions, which has been interrupted **without any warning**.
I'm waiting.
Thanks.
E.

Comment: Please, is there anybody knowing something we don't know? We tried to contact people in forums and staff via mail, but nobody replay. We need to know if the service is definitively stopped or if it's only a permission problem.

Answer (score 1):

YQL has enabled the "use" statements in query.yahooapis.com.
Can you try again to see if this works now?
Thanks,
Gil

Comment: So Yahoo turned them off temporarily?

Comment: We realized yesterday that the service had been restored. Now it's working.

But after an interrupted launch campaign, 2 days lost trying to understand what was going on without anybody replaying to us, we were about to change the platform.

And now the question is: what do you want to do? We know that yahoo belongs now to Oath.

what will it be, in the future of yahoo "use" statement and "yql api"? Will the service be maintained and enhanced or it will be permanently interrupted, perhaps without warning, as happened a few days ago?

Thanks. E.F.

Comment: Please note: the external YQL endpoint is being retired today. 
https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an email to Flurry support yesterday and they responded that they would contact the right people. I just now tried running a query with an external table, it's working again...for now.

Comment: Yes, for now, our external tables too are working fine. But the question are: what's the future of this service? How can we edit the content of our existing open data tables without yql console? What is the flurry support email? We sent several mails to yql support... but nobody replied to us. Thanks. E.F.

Comment: @ENRICOFACCHINETTI The console disappeared late Nov. '17, same with the builtin html table in early June same year. No warning or announcements, things just suddenly disappear. Social media for YDN and YQL stopped talking about YQL long time ago. In my opinion YQL should no longer be used in production environments. There is no clear support channel, they instead urge users to use SO with #yql and let users fend for themselves. Where did you find a mail address for YQL support? Due to lack of options, I used support@flurry.com, found on the bottom of https://developer.yahoo.com/support/flurry/

Answer (score 0):

Please note: the external YQL endpoint is being retired today. 
https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

Comment: Yes, the external YQL endpoint is being retired for good. It had a good and long run.

Comment: Alerting the day before the final interruption of such a delicate and strategic service, demonstrates a degree of inadequacy and inefficiency that leads us to think "never again yahoo / oath".